# Flask Select Field Form Registers as None

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am immensely baffled by what should be very simple in my forms as I have this same construct working in other areas of my Flask web application. Below is a route I have:

```
@data_tools.route('/dataTools', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def data_tools_upload():
    table = '<table></table>' 
    result = '<table></table>' 
    message = ''
    var2use = None 
    vars = ''
    dt_name = ''
    dtRadios = dtFormRadio(request.form)
    bins = 5
    foo=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tmp_filename = tempfile.gettempdir()+'\\input.csv'
        if request.files:
            to_upload = request.files.get('file')
            dt_name = str(to_upload).split()[1]
            if to_upload:
                f = request.files['file']
                f.save(tmp_filename)
        if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
            orig_df = pd.read_csv(tmp_filename)
            vars = list(orig_df.columns)

            ## Testing new form part
            #dtRadios.varlist.choices = vars 
            foo = dtRadios.varlist.data            
            ## end test

            var2use = request.form.get("var2use")
            if var2use != None:
                indx = vars.index(var2use)
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'descriptives':
                    result = dt.get_descriptives(orig_df[vars[indx]])
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'percentiles':
                    result = dt.get_percentiles(orig_df[vars[indx]])
                if dtRadios.dtRadioList.data == 'frequency':
                    if dtRadios.binSize.data != None:
                        bins = dtRadios.binSize.data
                    result = dt.get_frequency(orig_df[vars[indx]], bins = bins)
                result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index', columns = [var2use]).to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover', header = "true", justify = "center")
            dims = orig_df.shape
            message = 'Data file %s with %s rows and %s columns loaded.' % (dt_name, dims[0],dims[1])
            table = orig_df.head(10).to_html(classes='data', header = "true")
    return render_template('dataTools.html', results = [result], message = message, vars = vars, var_name = var2use, dtForm=dtRadios, foo=foo)
```

and then here is a form I have built to go along with this

```
class dtFormRadio(FlaskForm):
    dtRadioList = RadioField('Choose Option:', choices=[('descriptives','Get Descriptives'),
        ('percentiles','Get Percentiles'), ('frequency','Get Frequency')])     
    #varlist = SelectField('Choose a variable',  [DataRequired()], coerce=str)
    varlist = SelectField('Choose a Variable', choices=[('clean', 'Clean/Processed Text'),('original', 'Original Text String')])   
    binSize = IntegerField('Bin Size', [DataRequired()], default = 10)
```

The relevant part of my question surrounds this line `foo = dtRadios.varlist.data`. It always evaluates to `None`. I'm printing it to my HTML output as `foo` just so I can see what python sees. When I replace this with `foo = dtRadios.binSize.data` or with `foo = dtRadios.dtRadioList.data` then whatever option is chosen in that part of the form is printed to screen (and it also works in the context of my app).

But, something about `foo = dtRadios.varlist.data` is not being evaluated. Does anyone see an obvious error in my code or my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Grr, solved problem. My `dtRadios.varlist` was in my HTML, but outside of the form whereas the other parts were properly inside the form. So, the submit button wasn't updating this part of the form.